`man` in package.json does not work for scoped npm package
having a npm package where added man in the package.json and also generate the man file with .1
below is the folder structure
.
├── bin
│   └── health-check.js
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── docs
│   └── gh-repo-care.md
├── LICENSE
├── man
│   └── git-repo-care.1
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── repo-care.code-workspace
├── src
│   ├── assets
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── index.js
│   └── other


and here is my package.json
{
  "name": "@xkeshav/gh-repo-care",
  "version": "2.2.4-alpha.2",
  "private": false,
  "displayName": "github-repo-care",
  "publisher": "@xkeshav",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/xkeshav/gh-repo-care/blob/main/README.md",
  "license": "MIT",
  "directories": {
    "bin": "bin",
    "man": "man",
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "man": "man/gh-repo-care.1",
  "files": [
    "__templates/**",
    "src/**",
    "man/**"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "check": "prettier --check  .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"",
    "prepublish": "npm run man",
    "version": "npm publish --access=public",
    "man": "marked-man --version \"git-open $npm_package_version\" --manual \"Git manual\" --section 1 docs/gh-repo-care.md > man/git-repo-care.1",
    "nuke": "rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json"
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "createdOn": "29 Sep 2024",
    "updatedOn": "10 Oct 2024"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "enquirer": "2.4.1",
    "fs-extra": "11.2.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "replace-in-file": "8.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "marked-man": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "3.3.3"
  }
}

and run npm publish --tag alpha
and install the specific version in another project but when run
man @xkeshav/gh-repo-care it does not work ;
also tried man gh-repo-care but didnt work,
also installed the package globally and tried but man did not work
what am I doing wrong here?
Repo link

Just a quick wild guess: try man @xkeshav/gh-repo-care-gh-repo-care. From docs: "If the filename doesn't start with the package name, then it's prefixed."

it says man: @xkeshav/gh-repo-care-gh-repo-care: No such file or directory No manual entry for @xkeshav/gh-repo-care-gh-repo-care

Honestly, this looks like a bug in npm. I don't usually install anything with npm globally (hell, there are better languages to write CLI utils), but now tried several packages with man present in their package.json (covering system's 9.4.2 and node 18 with npm 10.9.0 via nvm), and none of those produced manpages. Consider opening a ticket in npm repo and linking it here for future reference.
